# Create a directive from an angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that populates some data for me using an AJAX call. This call receives a string that contains a literal directive within it, as well as some other text. I want to parse the received string so that it actually creates the desired directives, but am having absolutely no luck. The directives will reside within a table, so I'm a little wary about doing any sort of DOM manipulation to get it working.

Here's a simplified example of this case which is not currently working: http://plnkr.co/edit/RM5FrUxAP1VVF55vSzK7?p=preview

```
  angular.module('docsIsolateScopeDirective', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$parse',
      function($scope, $parse) {
        $scope.data="A"
        $scope.mydir = $parse('<my-dir info=data></my-dir>');
      }
    ])
    .directive('myDir', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          info: '='
        },
        template: '{{info}}'
      };
    });
```

If there's a better way to go about it, I'm also happy to hear it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use $compile to achieve this. Here is the plnkr, See if this helps

http://plnkr.co/edit/GbaA9yo6QjOVHNfw3jzA?p=preview

```
 .directive('dynamicDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   replace: true,
   scope:{
     content:'='
   },
   link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('content', function(html) {
    ele.append( $compile(html)(scope.$parent));
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
...
.directive('myDir', function ($sce) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-bind-html="$sce.trustAsHtml(info)"></div>',
        scope: { info: '=' },
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.$sce = $sce;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! How would I call this from the controller?

Comment: Don't use directives in controller, and use directives in templates instead, like this: `<my-dir info="'<span>html string</span>'"></my-dir> `

Comment: I take the text out of an ajax call, which makes it difficult to pass in from the template, though.

Comment: just put the ajax result to the $scope, like this: `$scope.ajaxResult=result`, then you can write you template code like this: `<my-dir info="ajaxResult"></my-dir>`